# What is the best way to send sensor data to my computer from my android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sensors

I have built an android app that starts to monitor sensor data when clicked on start and stops when clicked on stop. I need to send this data to my server(in this case my computer) through a PHP script, I have thought of the following solutions 
1. To send each data point as the data is being monitored.
2. To store the data on the phone's storage and send it once the stop button is clicked.
3. To store the data on the SQL database and then send the data to the server once stop is pressed.

I'm a beginner to android and I'm not able to understand which one of the above methods would be the best. I would also like to know how to implement these methods.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How would the methods cope with communication not working?

- Option 1, to cope would require the data to be stored to prevent data loss.

What is the difference between 2 and 3, as an SQlite database would be stored on the phone's storage? How if not using 3 would 2 work?

How do you prevent duplication of data?

I believe that aksing yourself these questions will result in the most useful and resillient method.